# Where do GOOGLEFINANCE((“CURRENCY:xxx xxx”)) takes the prices from?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I'm using the `GOOGLEFINANCE((“CURRENCY:USDARS”))` function to convert US DOLLARS to ARGENTINIAN PESOS.

I wanted to know where do Google take the prices from? I'm comparing with our local trade values and there's a small difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SIX Financial Information, according to [here](https://www.google.com/intl/en/googlefinance/disclaimer/?ei=sKtTWfH-D4rDU-6ygbAK), with a three minute delay.

Comment: Thanks, Regarding Argentina it says: BCBA, Bolsa de Comercio de Buenos Aires, 20min delay

Comment: ah ok! so for currency prices it gets the info from SIX Financial information, I get it....